# Ошибка при передачи элемента одного массива, другому

Tags: vba

При передачи из одного массива элемент приравнивается к нулю, хотя должен равняться другому числу[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Sub CH()
    Dim s As Integer, m = New Integer() {14, 6, 3, 0, 7, 12, -3, 1, 5, 2, -10}, k(1) As Integer, f As Integer, t As Integer
    f = 0
    For i = 0 To 10
        If (m(i) Mod 3) = 0 Then
            s += m(i)
            k(f) = m(i)
            ReDim Preserve k(UBound(k) + 1)
            If k(f) > k(f + 1) Then
                k(f) = t
                k(f + 1) = k(f)
                k(f + 1) = t
            End If
            Vivod(k(f), ListBox1)
            f += 1
        End If
    Next i
    Vivod1(s, TextBox1)

End Sub
```

После комментария ниже, я изменил код и теперь выдает вот такой результат[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    Sub CH()
    Dim s As Integer, m = New Integer() {14, 6, 3, 0, 7, 12, -3, 1, 5, 2, -10}, k(0) As Integer, f As Integer, t As Integer
    f = 0
    For i = 0 To 10
        If (m(i) Mod 3) = 0 Then
            s *= m(i)
            k(f) = m(i)
            ReDim Preserve k(UBound(k) + 1)
            f += 1
        End If
    Next i
    Vivod1(s, TextBox1)

    For d = 0 To f - 1
         For i = 1 To f - 1 - d
             If k(i) > k(i + 1) Then
                 t = k(i + 1)
                 k(i + 1) = k(i)
                 k(i) = t
             End If
         Next
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать в SO! Несколько встречных вопросов. Почему Вы накапливаете в S сумму, если в условии задачи речь идёт о произведении?

Comment: Зачем нужна проверка сразу после увеличения размера массива k? Новый элемент k(f + 1) в любом случае будет нолём. Или это попытка выполнить сортировку "на лету"? Не стоит этого делать, сделайте две отдельных операции - накопление нужных данных в массиве k при просмотре исходного массива m и только потом сортировка. При обмене значений местами в сортировке первый оператор записывается наоборот - сначала присвоить t значение элемента массива k

Comment: @JohnSUN ох да, это я ошибся, что начал считать сумму

Comment: @JohnSUN Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @JohnSUN теперь при сортировке неправильно сортирует

Comment: Ну, скажем так, сортирует правильно, но не до конца. Цикл проходит по всем элементам массива ОДИН раз и меняет соседние элементы. Чтобы сдвинуть -3 к началу массива, а 12 к концу, одного прохода не достаточно. То есть нужен ещё один вложенный цикл от 1 до f. Примеров сортировки в Сети много, "пузырёк" считается одним из самых простых алгоритмов. Последовательность действий при заполнении K не совсем логичная - наверное стоит увеличивать размер массива перед внесением очередного элемента: начать с `f = -1`, для очередного элемента увеличить f, ReDim массив k до f и потом k(f)=m(i)

Comment: К слову сказать, описание i в Dim не вижу, не аккуратненько как-то. Именно эту переменную можно было бы использовать для внутреннего цикла в сортировке

Comment: Извини, опечатка - внутренний цикл должен начинаться с **d+**1

Answer (score 0):

Рабочая часть кода может быть похожа на это:

```
f = -1
s = 1    ' Важно! В противном случае результат для любого набора данных будет 0
For i = LBound(m) To UBound(m)
    If (m(i) Mod 3) = 0 Then
        s = s * m(i)
        f = f + 1
        ReDim Preserve k(f)
        k(f) = m(i)
    End If
Next i

For d = 0 To f - 1
    For i = d + 1 To f
        If k(d) > k(i) Then
            t = k(d)
            k(d) = k(i)
            k(i) = t
        End If
    Next i
Next d

TextBox1.Value = s  ' Зачем нужны Vivod и Vivod1?
ListBox1.List = k
```

[image: Результат.png]

Comment: выводы нужны для замороченного препода, который обязует делать через процедуру, а так спасибо, я уже разобрался